# Tips to deploy the project from Eclipse IDE to another organization

Tags: integration

I am trying to deploy my sandbox project to Developer edition from Ecilipse by using Force.com IDE, But the pbm is I am getting lots  error , in the debug log when we validate the deployment.

Do we need follow some rules before deployment to destination like Object should deploy frist, relation should go first . I did lots of thing in Sandbox for my project like created number of objects, define the realtion, use those relation in form of query in Apex code.. Now I am getting error specially in classes like this relation is not presten in this query like that . I am giving the example of error here ::

Deploy Results:
   File Name:    objects/CampaignMember.object
   Full Name:  CampaignMember.LeadSource
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1343494669-6589 (21090395)

File Name:    objects/CaseTypeTests_*c.object
   Full Name:  CaseTypeTests*_c.TestName_*c
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Field TestName*_c does not exist. Check spelling.

File Name:    objects/Case_Accession__c.object
   Full Name:  Case_Accession__c
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: casepopulate does not exist or is not a valid override for action Edit.

File Name:    objects/Contact.object
   Full Name:  Contact.LeadSource
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED

Problem: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1343494669-6590 (21090395)

File Name:    objects/Lead.object
   Full Name:  Lead.LeadSource
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1343494669-6591 (21090395)

File Name:    objects/Opportunity.object
   Full Name:  Opportunity.LeadSource
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1343494669-6592 (21090395)

File Name:    objects/Opportunity.object
   Full Name:  Opportunity.SyncedQuoteId
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: fullName must end with: __c or __kav or __x or __y

File Name:    objects/Quote.object
   Full Name:  Quote
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Invalid fullName, must end in __c

File Name:    objects/QuoteLineItem.object
   Full Name:  QuoteLineItem
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Invalid fullName, must end in __c

File Name:    objects/Specimen_*c.object
   Full Name:  Specimen*_c
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: The sharing model cannot be updated through the API.

File Name:    objects/Test_*c.object
   Full Name:  Test*_c
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED

Problem: The sharing model cannot be updated through the API.

FYI all is working on Sandbox environment.

Please provide any suggestion for these kind of deployment.

Regards
Raman

Comment: I find that usually there is only one problem but that it then cascades into multiple errors. When the first object/class etc fails it is then not there for anything else to reference when it needs to. If you fix the first issue you will probably find that many of the errors will 'disappear'.
As far as deployment tips go if it is a big deployment with many components I usually deploy sObjects, Fields and other structural stuff first and then any apex/vf pages after that. Mind you I'm no expert - just my preference...

Comment: @ITMANHAH, Thank you very much ITMANHAH at-least you shown some interest in my problem , I have posted this question every where but no help. I guess you r clear with my requirement,, Don't we have anything which will take care all of this stuff automatically (Means dependency of one metadata to another) If I will deploy like this after checking all dependency manually than it will take lots of time for deployment, my project is very big ?? One more thing My code coverage is 0%, this is also the pbm in deployment...... Any help  is appreciable.

Comment: Find the root cause of the first error and solve that then try to redeploy. If it fails repeat above... Make sure that all your test classes are included in the deployment especially the tests for the triggers as these are a must. If all required tests and components successfully deploy all the tests are then run. There must be at least 75% code coverage which is calculated as part of the deployment. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Sadly some of these issues look like you may need to make manual changes before your deployment will be processed successfully. The following details may help resolve some of the issues.

**Lead Source**

> File Name: objects/CampaignMember.object Full Name: CampaignMember.LeadSource Action: NO ACTION Result: FAILED Problem: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1343494669-6589 (21090395)
>
> File Name: objects/Contact.object Full Name: Contact.LeadSource Action: NO ACTION Result: FAILED Problem: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1343494669-6590 (21090395)
>
> File Name: objects/Lead.object Full Name: Lead.LeadSource Action: NO ACTION Result: FAILED Problem: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1343494669-6591 (21090395)
>
> File Name: objects/Opportunity.object Full Name: Opportunity.LeadSource Action: NO ACTION Result: FAILED Problem: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1343494669-6592 (21090395)

This issue may be that the Lead Source field (on Lead / Account / Contact / Opportunity and CampaignMember) cannot be modified in the metadata API when more than one of those objects are included. This is to do with all of those fields using the same underlying metadata. Manually deploy the changes to one of the Source fields (e.g. Lead Source on Lead), and you will see the same picklist value changes on all the other objects. If this is the issue then re-running this deployment of the values will mean the "Unexpected errors" should no longer occur. You could also try deploying one of these 4 objects on its own.

This issue also occurs with the Industry field on Lead and Account.

As Andrew Fawcett's comment says, I would still log a support ticket with salesforce for the error you had encountered, along with these details if what I suggest resolves it.

**Quotes**

> File Name: objects/Opportunity.object Full Name: Opportunity.SyncedQuoteId Action: NO ACTION Result: FAILED Problem: fullName must end with: __c or __kav or __x or __y
>
> File Name: objects/Quote.object Full Name: Quote Action: NO ACTION Result: FAILED Problem: Invalid fullName, must end in __c
>
> File Name: objects/QuoteLineItem.object Full Name: QuoteLineItem Action: NO ACTION Result: FAILED Problem: Invalid fullName, must end in __c

This issue looks like quotes are not enabled. Setup -> Quotes -> Settings -> Enable quotes may resolve this.

**Sharing Model Changes**

> File Name: objects/Specimen_c.object Full Name: Specimen_c Action: NO ACTION Result: FAILED Problem: The sharing model cannot be updated through the API.
>
> File Name: objects/Test_c.object Full Name: Test_c Action: NO ACTION Result: FAILED Problem: The sharing model cannot be updated through the API.

You cannot modify an object's sharing model via the metadata API, again you need to do this manually through the UI. Setup -> Security Controls -> Sharing Settings

Answer (score 0):

**Unhandled Platform Errors.** I see a lot of unhanded platform exceptions (potential bugs in the platform) in your log. Its very hard to figure out what these mean sometimes, as they are likely masking the main root cause (likely a missing component), raise a support case and pass on the details as per the message.

**Creating a Temporary Unmanaged Package.** You might want to consider creating a [Package](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/creating_packages.htm) (Setup > Create) in your Sandbox org and adding some key components to that (objects, apex classes, triggers, vf pages etc). Packages handle dependency management for you, so adding these items will draw in other things they need. You can upload it, once it gives you a Package Install URL you can use it to install into your Developer Edition org. You can delete the Package definition from your Sandbox when your done.